# How do I add Jinja2 to my cherrypy project?

Tags: python, cherrypy, jinja2

I have this tool right here

http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Jinja

but what do I do with this?

Comment: What are you confused by?  How to load this so that it is registered with CherryPy?  Or how to use the tool once it is loaded?  And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

This tool allows you to render your response using jinga templates. Read the usage...

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.jinja(filename='index.html')
def controller(**kwargs):
    return {

    } # This dict is the template context
```